# How many SSL certificates needed for load balanced web servers

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, iis-arr

I have 3 servers. 1 is IIS-ARR load balancer. 2 servers are IIS web servers with my website hosted. I want to run the website on https. So how many SSL certificates are needed, which servers I have to create SSL CSR request and Which servers I have to install them.

Comment: Why down vote for this question.

Comment: You can try to use Centralized SSL Certificate to share the same customer certificate between all ARR machines. For more information, see [Centralized SSL Certificate Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-centralized-ssl-certificate-support-ssl-scalability-and-manageability)

Comment: I have only 1 ARR load balancer machine. And 2 IIS we servers .  To create SSL on ARR, do I need to create CSR on default web site.

Comment: Plz try to answer my question "SSL for ARR load balancer to manage 2 websites".

Comment: If you want a simple solution and free, you can setup an nginx load balancer that proxies the calls according to your rules and configure a cloudflare dns to that nginx server and you get https for free and more simple

Comment: OK. Let me check.

Comment: I want to use Windows Server OS for LoadBalancer. But as per this link. https://upcloud.com/community/tutorials/configure-load-balancing-nginx/?utm_term=&utm_campaign=DSA&utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=ppc&hsa_acc=9391663435&hsa_cam=7185608860&hsa_grp=81739862313&hsa_ad=391197952986&hsa_src=g&hsa_tgt=dsa-460992423274&hsa_kw=&hsa_mt=b&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIpJq1joHO6gIVgX8rCh3TbgTIEAAYASAAEgIBFfD_BwE.  Nginx  is not available for windows. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this from another query. I need to use a certificate with Subject Alternate Names which is authorized for multiple domains.
Such a certificate could, once installed where the CSR was created in order to pair it with the private key, be exported as a bundle including the private key then imported on all involved servers.
So, just 1 certificate will solve the purpose.